# Embedding Excel File Onto a Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an editable GridView in my ASP.NET Website which I want to Replace with an Editable Excel document. From my previous searches I've found that by using Microsoft Office or Google Docs we can only View the Excel file, but need to upload it to a Google Drive or One Drive to edit it. I need to have my excel document edited from my own hosted without being uploaded anywhere. Please help.

Comment: "*I need to have my excel document edited from my own hosted without being uploaded anywhere*" - it looks like you asking to help you create your own Google Docs.....

Comment: i'm looking for ways to make the doc editable from my website itself. when i tried using live.office.com web viewer it asked me to upload the doc to onedrive which i need to override

Comment: It is exactly called "creation of my own Google Docs". You want to create web interface for editing excel file. How is it different from Google Docs idea (ok, subset of Google Docs conceringn to Excel)?. It is very complicated task, and there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: Why do you think you need Excel editing? What kind of editing do you want? Editing data in a grid and editing an Excel are two completely different things. Excel has a **lot** of features which you can't hope to implement but your users will be very upset if they are missing. You can buy a third-party control like FarPoint's Spread for ASP.NET but don't expect full compatibility

Comment: Currently, I'm offering a GridView for my users and If they want to edit changes themselves then they had to download the document through an option provided and then upload the edited doc later on. Now I want to offer editing from the View itself by forwarding the path to a web app like live offcie @Panagiotis

Comment: That's a full blown product, not a script or control on a page. It's like comparing a bicycle to a car. Check the available third-party controls to find which offers the features you want but don't expect them to offer everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a JQuery plugin for excel like functionality.

[HandsOnTable](http://handsontable.com/)

It also has various integration options using Jquery, AngularJS, Bootstrap, Backbone.js whichever integration you choose depends on your choice.

Edit: A New CodeProject Article Can also help!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892137/Online-Spreadsheet-a-low-latency-html-websocket-Cl

Comment: Can I have functionalities like vlookup and other operations possible on it?

Comment: @ram, I am not aware about it. The complete source code is available on github which you can fork it for free. You can write a code to extend this to add support for vlookup if its not present.

Answer (score 0):

Consider reversing the problem.

Have your webpage Download the excel file from your host and open it in excel. Then have a custom excel add in replicate the extra functionality/look and feel of your website. when saving trigger an upload of the file back to your host.

a bit like sharepoint

Comment: looks like a good one. can you explain it a bit detail

Comment: SharePoint goes way beyond that - it *does* allow hosting Excel files, even calculation of formulas and basic editing. AND it's a huge product. I think you can install the Office Web Apps component separately, but it's still a separate product.

Comment: bit after the fact now a 'use java script' answer has been accepted, but my point was that if you want to edit your excel document with all the excel features its really the 'save to web' bit you want to program, not the 'all of excel' bit